# DataBind() within Parallel.Invoke failing due to Stack Empty. Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, parallel-processing, data-binding

I am not sure why this error is happening intermittently. I have a UserControl that is being data bound in parallel. The code works 90% of the time but every so often the databind will fail and will receive the below error.

```
   at System.Collections.Stack.Pop()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.CreateItem(Int32 itemIndex, ListItemType itemType, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean useDataSource)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
```

Anyone know why this is happening and how to avoid ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a concurrency issue.  Instance methods on web controls [are not guaranteed to be type-safe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx).  As a result, DataBind (and other instance methods) should not be invoked simultaneously on multiple threads.

As to why this is happening: the [Control class implementation](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/Dotnetfx_Vista_SP2/Dotnetfx_Vista_SP2/8@0@50727@4016/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/whidbey/NetFxQFE/ndp/fx/src/xsp/System/Web/UI/Control@cs/1/Control@cs) includes an internal `Page` instance; this instance has an internal stack used for data binding.

```
protected virtual void DataBind(bool raiseOnDataBinding) {
    bool inDataBind = false;
    if (foundDataItem && (Page != null)) { 
        Page.PushDataBindingContext(dataItem);
        inDataBind = true;
    }
    try{
    //...
    } finally {
        if (inDataBind) { 
            Page.PopDataBindingContext(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Normally, each push would be accompanied by a later pop, ensuring the stack is never empty.  However, the Stack class itself is array-based, and the array is copied to a larger array when it fills.  If multiple values are pushed simultaneously when the array is being copied, the copy operation could in some cases be conducted twice, with all but being lost.  When this happens in the context of a `PushDataBindingContext`, the data item is never actually pushed to the stack -- when the method later attemts to pop the item it pushed from the stack, the stack is empty and the exception is thrown.

Comment: thanks drf, that is definitely the right answer. now to only figure out how to do this in parallel without the threading issues...

Answer (score 1):

The exception is likely a thread-safety issue.  In particular, if you have multiple threads running code like this in parallel:

```
// s is a instance of Stack
if (s.Count > 0)
     s.Pop()
```

the stack can be emptied by another thread between the `s.Count` and `s.Pop()` calls.  The subsequent call to `s.Pop()` fails since the stack is empty.

One (recommended) alternative in C# 4 is to use `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentStack` in place of `Stack`.  This class includes the method `TryPop`, which will return (as an out parameter) the top item in the stack if the stack is not empty, and false otherwise.  Since the process is atomic, the operation is thread-safe.

A second option is to lock the stack using the `SyncRoot` property:

```
lock(s.SyncRoot)
{
    if (s.Count > 0)
       s.Pop();
}
```

This will prevent multiple threads from removing items from the stack simultaneously.

Comment: drf, thank you for the reply. The only thing is that I am not using a stack inside of my DataBind(). The UserControls *base* DataBind() (Microsoft's code) uses the stack (I dont know the internals of this databind).

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.  I see what the problem is and am replacing this with a new answer.